# ADWtest needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I enabled Azure AD App Service Authentication for one of the app service. Now I'm getting below error when I try to login using my Azure AD credentials.

**ADWtest needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, your app(ADWtest) has permissions which need your admin's consent. You can use your admin account to sign in to grant the permission, or go to azure portal with your admin account to grant admin consent.

[image]

By the way, if you just use the express management mode with the default value, you shouldn't get this issue.

[image]